# Oracle APEX: filters are showing incorrectly in the 'Interactive Grid' screen, and taking up a lot of space and showing wrong why?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1, oracle-apex-5

The filters are showing incorrectly in the 'Interactive Grid' screen, and taking up a lot of space and showing wrong why?

[image: Wrongly taken image]

It has to come actually like below, the image below is taken from another grid , in one its coming correctly and another is wrong why ?

[image: Correct image]

Comment: Which Apex version do you really use?